# Convert JSON objects to table structure in Python

Tags: python, json, export, export-to-csv

I have some JSON with an 'items list. I want to convert it to semicolon separated file with headers

I want to produce lines in this format: `id, date, order[x][0], order[x][1], ...`

My issue is that I need to include headers, the names of the fields, and some `order` items do not have all the possible elements so I can't just join the values together.

for the JSON below I'd expect the following output:

```
id;date;prefix;number;quantity;code;index
06107;2023-09-25T01:51:04Z;VO;32233809;1;;4
06107;2023-09-25T01:51:04Z;VO;31438125;1;;4
06107;2023-09-25T10:00:51Z;VO;31407983;1;14;4
06107;2023-09-25T10:00:51Z;VO;986116;6;12;4
```

I'm guessing maybe some kind of panda usage would be the solution, but I'm not sure how to make the mapping and export.

```
        "items": [
            {
                "id": "06107",
                "date": "2023-09-25T01:51:04Z",
                "order": [
                    {
                        "prefix": "VO",
                        "number": "32233809",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "index": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "prefix": "VO",
                        "number": "31438125",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "index": 4
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "06107",
                "date": "2023-09-25T10:00:51Z",
                "order": [
                    {
                        "prefix": "VO",
                        "number": "31407983",
                        "quantity": 1,
                        "code": 14,
                        "index": 4
                    },
                    {
                        "prefix": "VO",
                        "number": "986116",
                        "quantity": 6,
                        "code": 12,
                        "index": 4
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest way to proceed is with a `csv.DictWriter()` passing `extrasaction="ignore"`.

Given:

```py
data = [
    {
        "id": "06107",
        "date": "2023-09-25T01:51:04Z",
        "order": [
            {"prefix": "VO", "number": "32233809", "quantity": 1, "index": 4},
            {"prefix": "VO", "number": "31438125", "quantity": 1, "index": 4}
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "06107",
        "date": "2023-09-25T10:00:51Z",
        "order": [
            {"prefix": "VO", "number": "31407983", "quantity": 1, "code": 14, "index": 4},
            {"prefix": "VO", "number": "986116", "quantity": 6, "code": 12, "index": 4}
        ]
    }
]
```

Then this code:

```py
import csv

headers = ["id", "date", "prefix", "number", "quantity", "code", "index"]
all_items = [
    {**item, **detail}
    for item in data
    for detail in item["order"]    
]

with open("foo.csv", "w", newline="") as file_out:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file_out, delimiter=";", fieldnames=headers, extrasaction="ignore")
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(all_items)
```

Will give you a file:

```
id;date;prefix;number;quantity;code;index
06107;2023-09-25T01:51:04Z;VO;32233809;1;;4
06107;2023-09-25T01:51:04Z;VO;31438125;1;;4
06107;2023-09-25T10:00:51Z;VO;31407983;1;14;4
06107;2023-09-25T10:00:51Z;VO;986116;6;12;4
```

A question was asked about how to proceed if the child attributes were unknown. A slight change to the structure of the program will allow us to accumulate the headers in a set.

```py
headers = set(["id", "date"])
all_items = []
for item in data:
    for detail in item["order"]:
        headers.update(detail.keys())
        all_items.append({**item, **detail})
```

Comment: Nice solution. You could simplify the `all_items.append` like that: `all_items.append({**item, **detail})`.
It would also have the advantage that if `id` or `date` are missing, the code will still work.

Comment: @nico sure, I'll make that change now

Comment: That is a really nice and simple solution! Is there anyway to dynamically get the headers from data? The JSON I have posted is a lot shorter than the real data and I'm not sure about the complete set of headers